# Add Time Values From Drop Downs To DatePicker Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm building an MVC 5 web application. Within one of the Razor Views I use a JQuery DatePicker to select a date from the Calender. Then I have two drop down menus, one to list each hour of the 24 Hour Clock, the other to list minute values, i.e., 1 - 60.

```html
<select id="startDateHours" name="startDateHours"><option value="00:00">00:00</option>
<option value="01:00">01:00</option>
<option value="02:00">02:00</option>
<option value="03:00">03:00</option>
<option value="04:00">04:00</option>
...
...
<option value="21:00">21:00</option>
<option value="22:00">22:00</option>
<option value="23:00">23:00</option>
</select>

<select id="startDateMinutes" name="startDateMinutes"><option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
...
...
<option value="57">57</option>
<option value="58">58</option>
<option value="59">59</option>
<option value="60">60</option>
</select>
```

Initially I had used the JQuery DateTimePicker, but my client found the plugin difficult to use.

I need to take the value from the DatePicker and combine it with the selected values from the two drop downs in order to create one DateTime value which I can then insert into my SQL Server Database table.

Within my MVC Controller I can retrieve the values like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel model)
{
     DateTime _date = model.StartDate //Value from DatePicker
     String _hour = model.StartDateHour //Value from drop down for hour
     String _min = model.StartDateMinute //Value from drop down for minute

     //Create DateTime object using values above
}
```

Now I need to combine the 3 values to create a DateTime object and I don't know how.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new DateTime with the following overload:

```
new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
```

example:

```
var myDate = new DateTime(model.StartDate.Year, model.StartDate.Month, model.StartDate.Day, _hour, _min, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you don't have another way of getting the Data needed, this should do the trick.

I'm assuming that _date has the Time 0:00 when you get  it. Otherwise you might want to set that first.

But in the line of the comment just do the following:

```
date = _date.Add(TimeFrame.Parse(_hour));
date = _date.AddMinutes(double.Parse(_min));
```

Please tell me if that is what you wanted :-)